# Does fprintf not accept an array of characters?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, printf, typecast-operator

I keep getting an error/warning about the argument of write_file making a pointer from integer without cast.

I'm trying to write an array of characters to file.  I thought that an array of characters would be received by fprintf.
here's the code:  (error message at end)

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

char take_char();
void write_file(char ch[10]);

int main(){
    char ch;
    ch = take_char();
    write_file(ch);
    printf("successfully worked");
    return 0;
}

char take_char(){
    char ch;
    printf("Please input a character:\n");
    scanf("%s", &ch);
    return ch;
}

void write_file(char ch[10]){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Jormak\\Desktop\\C_practicing\\Projects\\file_main.txt","w");

    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("FILE did not open.");
    }
    else{
        printf("Successfully opened the file");
    }

    fprintf(fp,ch[10]);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Error message:

THIS IS THE ERROR:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:10:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘write_file’ makes pointer from     integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  write_file(ch[10]);
  ^
main.c:5:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 void write_file(char ch[10]);
      ^
main.c: In function ‘write_file’:
main.c:33:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fprintf’ makes pointer from     integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  fprintf(fp,ch[10]);
```

^
    In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:29:0,
                 from main.c:1:
    /usr/include/stdio.h:173:5: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of     type ‘char’
     int _EXFUN(fprintf, (FILE *__restrict, const char *__restrict, ...)
     ^

Comment: You're passing a char to function that takes a char array (write_file) and also passing a char to fprintf, which takes a char*

Comment: "THIS IS THE ERROR " ... um... that isn't the only error: `scanf("%s", &ch);`  - ouch.

Comment: You seem confused about the difference between a _single_ character, an array of characters, and a C string. I think you need to find a basic tutorial, or maybe start from the C FAQ, eg. [here](http://c-faq.com/charstring/index.html)